# Xorg lag spikes during gameplay

Tags: 12.10, xorg, games, cpu-load

With almost any game I play, be it Minecraft, TF2, World of Goo or windows games running in wine, I get horrible lag spikes (after a shot time playing) that happen about every 15-20 seconds and last for 2-4.

I have run "top" in the command line and can see that, very time the games lag, xorg jumps to the top (for the duration of the lag spike).

I'm using an Acer Aspire running Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit, with 8GB of ram and an Intel® Core™ i5-2450M CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4 processor.

It's driving me up the wall! If any of you kind souls know what the problem is and how to fix it, I would be eternally grateful!

Many thanks,
TheBlueBox

Comment: Per [user121906](http://askubuntu.com/a/250676/44179): What %of cpu does Xorg use in top during the lag? Is there any increased disk activity ?  What graphics card and driver to you have ?

Comment: I have the same problem and there is high disk activity during those lag spikes